What is the difference between Processor Status Word (PSW) and Program Status Word (PSW)?
As per Oxford dictionary;

Program Status Word
A collection of information that encapsulates the basic execution state of a program at any instant. It permits an interrupted process to resume operation after the interrupt has been handled. The information is held in the program status register, and usually contains the value of the program counter and bits indicating the status of various conditions in the ALU such as overflow and carry, along with the information on supervisor privileged status. The contents of other processor registers may also need to be preserved in memory after an interruption of a process and recovered when the interrupted process is resumed so that the complete process state is reestablished. See also processor status word.


Processor Status Word
A word that describes fully the condition of a processor at each instant. It indicates which classes of operations are allowed and which are forbidden, and the status of all interrupts associated with the processor. It will also contain the address of the instruction currently being executed. The PSW is held in a register known as the processor status register. See also program status word.

I find it hard to differentiate between the two. If asked an AI it will say those two terms are used interchangeably. Wikipedia has an entry for 'Program Status Word' but not for the 'Processor Status Word'.
Are those two terms really meant the same thing (in the implementation atleast)?
Web search and AI didn't help much.

These are both generic phrases.  There is no universal meaning.  Some processors will use one, some won't have one at all.

Different ISAs use different terminology for their https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Status_register if they have one, e.g. x86 calls it the FLAGS register, ARM calls it the PSR with P standing for Program.(https://developer.arm.com/documentation/den0013/d/ARM-Processor-Modes-and-Registers/Registers/Program-Status-Registers).  But your definitions have a single word holding the program counter + condition codes and other flags including interrupts, which is odd.  Sounds like something for a toy ISA that's simplified for teaching purposes, or maybe a very simple real ISA.

@TimRoberts Is PSW not necessary for entering and exiting the privileged state or the kernel mode?

That depends on the Instruction Set Architecture.  And what the register is called is entirely dependent on the ISA specifications.  I think you are looking for a distinction that doesn't exist.

@JacobMiller: Some simple CPU / MCUs don't support privilege separation or a kernel mode at all; all code has full access to all hardware.

On 8080 for example, the PSW (program status word) is the 8-bit accumulator plus an 8-bit flags register that isn't directly accessible, just by push psw and/or pop psw.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_8080#Registers

Trying to understand the definitions of technical terms from general English dictionaries is usually a waste of time.  In trying to make them accessible to a lay audience, they usually simplify them to a point that it's impossible to tell what the precise technical meaning is, or (as in this case) if there even is one.

@PeterCordes Thanks. That may explain a lot. I found it in the texts explaining the virtualization of early third-generation architectures using a simplified model as one of them says "Although idealized, notably because of the lack of registers, this architectural model is not fundamentally different from the ones that we are all familiar with".

I agree that it is silly to rely on dictionaries for this kind of thing.  Sorry, but the people who compile the OED are not experts in computer instruction sets / architectures.  At best they might be repeating something they found somewhere else.  But where did they find it?  Is it unambiguously correct?  How would they know?

Oh, I didn't notice these are from the OED, not a computer-architecture textbook or something.  No wonder they seem to conflate PSW with architectural state in general (program counter, GPRs).  I mean, there does have to be a way to save/restore condition codes on CPUs with status registers, so having a way to access it, e.g. via push/pop, is necessary to be able to write efficient interrupt handlers.  (Otherwise you'd need a lot of branching on each flag and mov of 0 or 1, then somehow restoring them by doing an add or whatever that produced the same set of flag results.)  So in that sense...

They do indeed seem interchangeable, in particular if your processor executes only a single program/process. It only makes sense to distinguish them if you also distinguish between processor state and program state, for example when discussing an operating system that executes multiple programs/processes.

Re: how does an ISA like RISC-V support privilege levels without a PSW:  It doesn't have condition-codes in a special register; it has slt (set if less-than) producing a boolean 0 or 1 in a GPR, and branch insns like blt target, x1, x2 that compare-and-branch on 2 register inputs.  But it does have an mstatus Machine Status Register with a user/supervisor bit and interrupt enable/disable etc. https://five-embeddev.com/riscv-priv-isa-manual/Priv-v1.12/machine.html#machine-status-registers-mstatus-and-mstatush  So that's the PSW, it just doesn't have ALU condition codes in it.

If your kernel isn't pre-emptible, RISC-V doesn't need to save/restore mstatus on interrupts: interrupts are disabled when already in kernel mode, so interrupt return is always to user-space. (Unless non-maskable interrupts exist?  Also, I think pre-emption in https://five-embeddev.com/baremetal/interrupts/ is only talking about interrupt handlers themselves being pre-empted.  IDK if RISC-V automatically saves/restores anything anywhere on interrupt.)  Anyway, in that sense it's not like a PSW on normal ISAs.  And it's not updated by every instruction.

Is PSW not necessary -- No.  The x86 architecture doesn't have one.  Kernel mode vs user mode is determined by the value of the CS code segment register.  Many small processors don't even have a kernel/user division.  Processors, as a rule, are more different then they are alike.
